# What is the most efficient way to traverse up in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-traversal

I'm trying to close a parent container when an internally nested button is clicked.  In my UI -- I have many of these parent containers (I'm rendering preview windows of my product catalogue on a product category page).

As you can see from my mark-up below -- the CLOSE button is deeply nested in the DOM.  When the user clicks on the CLOSE Button -- I need to hide() the parent Box-1.  Keep in mind I may have upto to 100 products being displayed on a page (100 boxes of "Box-1"s) at a time.

My markup looks like this:

```
<div class="box-1">
  <div class="box-2">
    <div class="box-3">...</div> <!-- end box-3 -->

    <div class="box-4">
      <div class="box-5">...</div> <!-- end box-5 -->
        <a class="btn-close" href="#">CLOSE</a>  <!-- this triggers the close event -->
    </div> <!-- end box-4 -->
  </div> <!-- end box-2 -->

  <div class="box-6">
    <div class="box-7">...</div> <!-- end box-7 -->

    <div class="box-8">
      ...
      <div class="box-9">...</div> <!-- end box-9 -->
    </div> <!-- end box-8 -->
  </div> <!-- end box-6 -->
</div> <!-- end box-1 -->
```

My question is -- how do I best (and most efficiently) traverse back up the DOM to get hold of the "box-1" and issue the .hide() method ... here is my existing code.

```
<script>
$productsResultItems.delegate('.btn-close', 'click', function (e) {
    //box-1
    $(this).parents('div.box-1').hide(); // <-- is this the best way?????
    e.preventDefault();
</script>
```

Initially, I was trying this --

```
$this.parents().find('.hover-box-large').hide();
```

which was proving to be very slow in IE7 and IE8.

I found adding more detail to the selector improved performance nearly 100-fold for IE7, but only 4-fold faster in IE8 :(  IE8 still requires about 200ms to close the parent container. Where now all other browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox and IE7) close the container in less than 20ms.

```
$this.parents('div.hover-box-large').hide();
```

But is there a selector method that is even better? Any particular reason IE8 is soooo bad at this type of upward traversal??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best method to use is [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest), which finds the nearest ancestor element that matches a selector:

```
$this.closest('div.box-1').hide();
```

Comment: Folks -- all three answers are correct. I'm granted the correct answer to lonesomeday as his/her came in first. Thank you all for your help. Using 'closest' was a great suggestion.  It cut IE8 rendering time by half!

Answer (score 3):

Actually `.closest()` should be quicker than `.parents()`.

In the [jQuery Docs on `.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), you can find:

> **.closest()**
>
> - Begins with the current element
> - Travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied selector
> - The returned jQuery object contains zero or one element
>
> **.parents()**
>
> - Begins with the parent element
> - Travels up the DOM tree to the document's root element, adding each ancestor element to a temporary collection; it then filters that
>     collection based on a selector if one is supplied
> - The returned jQuery object contains zero, one, or multiple elements

So in your case, `.closest()` would be the most suitable one, as you need to find one element, the closest ancestor that matches your selector. `parents()` would filter through all the possible ancestor elements, even if it already found the one you need.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between parents() and closest() is that closest() stops once it has found a match therefore always returning 0 or 1 elements.  Parents() will match everything up the DOM.

```
$(this).closest('.box-1').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks John -- great concise answer -- much appreciated. It cut the IE8 rendering time in half!

Answer (score 0):

Not so fast! `closest()` *may* be the best but not always! Here's how you can find out for yourself. Use the [Firebug time() and timeEnd()](http://getfirebug.com/logging) functions to actually log your calls. Then choose the one that is right for the situation.

```
// 59ms
console.time("Parent x 3");
$container = $element.parent().parent().parent();
console.timeEnd("Parent x 3");

// 3ms              
console.time("Closest parent");
$container = $element.closest('.some-class').parent();
console.timeEnd("Closest parent");

// 2ms              
console.time("Parents");
$container = $element.parents('.other-class').eq(1);
console.timeEnd("Parents");
```

Comment: +1 for testing to specific instances; your own DOM can affect things a lot. `console.time()` and `console.timeEnd()` are in Chrome too. Try doing these benchmarks in different orders as well: when I test `.closest()` first, five chained `.parent()` calls are just as fast, but if I test the `.parent()`s first and then `.closest()`, the `closest()` test takes half the time.